# creating the tagged values through addin

Tags: enterprise-architect

For the class type element We want to create the enum type tagged values through addin.We have an api element.taggedvalues.addnew("Sample","Enum") but it is creating the tag and not enum type through addin .So how can we achieve this through addin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily. The definition for such TVs are stored in the table `t_propertytypes` and you need to place it there. Now a newly created TV with that name will be an enum.

To add such a default you need to

```
pt = Repository.PropertyTypes
p = pt.AddNew("some TV", "")
p.Detail = "Type=Enum; Values=a,b,c;"
p.Update()
```

Now you can add a TV like

```
element.TaggedValues.AddNew("some TV", "this can by anything")
```

Note that the default value can also be something not being in the enum.

To check the existence of such a default you should be able to read `Repository.PropertyTypes`. But in my test got only a zero size collection. I suspect a bug in EA here. You can however issue a

```
Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT * FROM t_propertytypes")
```

and inspect the XML-result to find out whether a default is already present.

Comment: But how can we check whether the property is already existing or not